# recyclerview item changes button style after scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview with simple items - an item has an image, title and a button. When the user clicks on the button it needs to change its layout -> indicating that button is clicked (similar to checkbox functionality).

Problem is that when I click on a button, for example the second item, it behaves weirdly when I scroll - multiple items are toggled or the original one is untoggled. You can check it out in image here:

[GIF PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb9vy.gif)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
  {
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        toggleButtonStyle((Button)view);
    });
  }

public void toggleButtonStyle(Button toggle) 
{
    Context ctx = toggle.getContext();
    if (toggle.isActivated()) {
        toggle.setActivated(false);
        toggle.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.btn_purple_corners));
        toggle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.purple_light));
    } else {
        toggle.setActivated(true);
        toggle.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.btn_purple));
        toggle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.white));
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to get position of the item then apply your styling , what you are doing now is just styling one item and the styled item get recycled and used by other items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify position for a onBindView method, because it's called multiple times. If you are using AutoValue immutable types, you can try to make an Array of booleans where you'll be storing toggled states (true/false). Then in onBindViewMethod check a value of current position and style a button.

```
private boolean[] toggledChoices = new boolean[yourListWithItems.size()];

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (toggledChoices[position]) {
        toggleButtonStyle(true, holder.toggleButton);
    } else {
        toggleButtonStyle(false, holder.toggleButton;
    }

    holderVote.bToggleItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (!toggledChoices[position]) {
            toggledChoices[position] = true;
        } else {
            toggledChoices[position] = false;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some strange behavior too in the past.
For me it was solved by simply calling

```
toggle.invalidate();
```

after your if/else block. This forces the redraw. Try it, I was surprised too, that this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out my code

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GifGridAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DataModel model = arrayList.get(position);
    if (model.isToggle()) {
//Code for changing the button background color and text color
    } else {
//Code for changing the button background color and text color
    }


    holder.ivGif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    model.setToggle(!model.isToggle());
    notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using AutoValue library, so my model is immutable, that's why i use button.setActivated(true);